# Return attachment with $.ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, download

I have an iframe on my page, and inside that iframe I execute code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/SamplePage/ExportToExcel',
    async: false,
    data: par,
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Response is returned fine, however I don't get 'SAVE ATTACHMENT' dialog, nothing happens... To make things clear, headers are fine (content disposition, mime type etc,), as when I execute that export using plain form submission it works. It seems that it has something to do with ajax call. Will it work somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't get the Save As dialog when using AJAX. If you want to get this dialog simply provide a normal link to the download file:

```
<a href="/SamplePage/ExportToExcel">download</a>
```

or if you need a POST request:

```
<form action="/SamplePage/ExportToExcel" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="download" />
</form>
```

When you use AJAX to download a file the contents of this file is retrieved at the success callback but there's not much you can do with it: you cannot save it to the client computer and you cannot get Save As dialog.

Answer (score 9):

To extend Darin's answer, here's how I did it:

I have a hidden form, with a hidden input element to be used to dynamically hold the values I wish to convert/export:

```
<form id="svg_export_form" method="POST" style="display:none;visibility:hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="svg" />
</form>
```

Then I have this jQuery code to dynamically populate the elements with the post parameters, and then submit the form.

```
$('#svg_export_form > input[name=svg]').val(svg_code);
$('#svg_export_form').attr('action','api/reports/convert/svg/to/png');
$('#svg_export_form').submit();
```

And because the returned response (fro the api call) has a Content Disposition header set, this form submit action wont navigate the user away from the current page (but just returns the attachment) like a normal form submit, and thus still keeps the illusion of a typical Ajax submit :-)

Comment: nemesisfixx - thanks for this great response. Quick question... Is there any way for the original page to know when the attachment has been downloaded? For example - I'd like to prevent the user from clicking the download button more than once, so I disable it right after she clicks it. However, once the download is complete, I'd like to re-enable it (So she can request another download with new settings/inputs). Can this be done?

Comment: @mattstuehler, am not sure of a straight-forward approach, but u could probably fire a server-side call to the fron-end (think Comet protocols) which would let your app know when the download was complete on the server-side. Another "easier" approach might be to just wait on a specific time-window, after whose expiration, u simply assume that the download must be complete, and u can then display the button (some prior info about yo average file size might  help).